# Java generic methods, wildcard List return type

Tags: java, generics

Java's 8 method signature looks as follows:

```
public static <E extends CharSequence> List<? super E> m(List<E> list);
```

And somewhere in code, method call:

```
result = m(list);
```

Suppose that I've create argument `list` as follows:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

My question is, why the `result` can be just raw `List`, and can't be even a `List<Object>`?

Comment: Im asking why my `result` can't be a `List<Object>` or `List<String>` for example. It can be just raw `List`.

Comment: Why do you use a wildcard as a return type? That is a rather strange thing to do...

Comment: @fge Thats library method, not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling your method with a `List<String>` as an argument is like calling the following method:

```
public static List<? super String> m(List<String> list) { ... }
```

Consider the following starting code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super String> result = m(list);
```

This calls the above mentioned method and stores the return value into the variable `result` - which is typed exactly with the method's return type.

The question now is: To what variables - or better what types - can you assign this variable? So we are speaking about assignment compatibility.

Consider these assignments:

```
List<String> result1 = result; // compiler error: type mismatch (not assignable)
List<Object> result2 = result; // compiler error: type mismatch (not assignable)

List result3 = result; // ok
List<?> result4 = result; // ok

List<? super String> result5 = result; // ok
List<? extends Object> result6 = result; // ok
```

To understand the nature of this error, you must know that generics are *invariant*. That means, the type `List<String>` *is not* a subtype of `List<Object>` - although the types `String` and `Object` have such a subtype hierarchy.

So, what we are trying here is:

1. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<String>` => fails, no subtyping
2. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<Object>` => fails, no subtyping
3. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List` => succeeds, because using raw types opts out from type checking generally
4. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<?>` => succeeds, because a `List<?>` is the supertype of all `List<...>`
5. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<? super String>` => succeeds, because ... well ...
6. Assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<? ectends Object>` => succeeds, because `List<? ectends Object>` is essentially the same as `List<?>`.

Note, that trying to assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<? super CharSequence>` or a `List<? extends CharSequence>` will also fail. They are not in a subtype hierarchy.

Why is that so? The compiler cannot guarantee that the actual list was instantiated with a type that matches the constraint `? super/extends CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do that is because Java generics are not covariant. That is, `List<Object>` is *not* a super-class of `List<String>`. The method signature of your method `m` would however allow returning a `List<String>`, and then you would have a `List<Object>` typed reference pointing to `List<String>`. Since generic type information is not available at run time, this would not raise an exception immediately, but it could result in type errors in unrelated places.

For example, suppose `m` is implemented as follows:

```
private static List<CharSequence> theResult = new ArrayList<>();

public static <E extends CharSequence> List<? super E> m(List<E> list) {
    theResult.addAll(list);
    return theResult;
}
```

Then using your method as follows would ad a non-`CharSequence` object to a `List<CharSequence>`:

```
List<Object> os = m(someList);
os.add(new Object());
```

Luckily, the above does not compile.